# How to add items into VisualStates and change row/column definitions?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am creating a Windows 10 Universal App. 
Of Course it should work on many devices. In this example it´s a 5" Phone and a 23" Desktop. I have finished the xaml stuff for the Desktop now. On the Desktop I have a grid called mainGrid. This grid has column and row definitions.

Now my Problem:
In the 5" Mode I Need of Course a ScrollViewer and the whole grid and row definitions are different (I know how to Change values but have no idea how to integrate new Elements and how to Change the definitions). On the phone view I Need 3 columns. The one in the middle is 6 times bigger than the two on the side.

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="_5__Phone">
                <VisualState.Setters>
          //   TODO?
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="0" MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="_23__Desktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="400" MinWindowWidth="800"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Frame Name="mainFrame">
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Thanks for your help.

```
                        <Setter Target="mainGrid.(Grid.RowDefinition)" Value="1*"/>
```

tried this but doesn´t work

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your layout for desktop, you have 4 column regions when on desktop, each have a same width and are separated with each other in a 0.1* space. Now you want to have 3 regions when on a Mobile, the one in the middle is 6 times bigger than the two on the side.

Then you can divide the Grid into 17 pieces and use the `VisualState` for example like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="_5__Phone">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="0" MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="grid1.Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="grid1.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="grid2.Grid.Column" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Target="grid2.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="11" />
                    <Setter Target="grid3.Grid.Column" Value="15" />
                    <Setter Target="grid3.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="grid4.Grid.Column" Value="16" />
                    <Setter Target="grid4.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="grid4.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="_23__Desktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="400" MinWindowWidth="800" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="grid1.Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="grid1.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Target="grid2.Grid.Column" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Target="grid2.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Target="grid3.Grid.Column" Value="9" />
                    <Setter Target="grid3.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Target="grid4.Grid.Column" Value="13" />
                    <Setter Target="grid4.Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Target="grid4.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Frame Name="mainFrame">
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red"></Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue"></Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="grid3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green"></Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="grid4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow"></Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

I took 4 `Grid`s to stand for 4 regions, you can continue to design your layout in these `Grid`s.

Comment: Let´s say I have one new grid(instead of four) and call it "mainGridMobile". In another part of this file i have four Buttons which have for Desktop Grid.Row and Grid.Column definitions. Now I want them to be on the new grid. And I want them to be on other rows and columns. For example: <Setter Target="button1name.Grid(?!?!).row???" I tried many ways but I get Errors then.

Comment: @omginput, do you want to move `Button` from one grid to another? If the original place and the target place are all in the same grid with definitions, It's the same, use `<Setter Target="button1name.Grid.Column" Value="2" />`, the value is the target grid definition's number. For the example here, this setter put the button in to the third column. But if the original place and the target place are in different `Grid`s, you can try to put the same button in both place and use `<Setter Target="button1name.Visibility" Value="Visible" />` to make it visible or not.

Comment: Is there any way to change the Grid.Column and Row definitions in the visualstate Setters section and have different RowColumn Definitions for them?